# Преобразование hstore при запросах

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, zend2, hstore

С HTML-формы приходит неструктурирование данные, т.е. какие-то поля могут приходить,а какие-то нет. Их получает бэкэнд на Zend Framework 2 и записывает в базу. Ну, или читает из базы.

Эти поля хочу хранить в hstore. Однако, что добавлять данные в hstore, что извлекать их в виде строки не очень удобно. Приходится писать дополнительный класс, который перед добавлением/выводом будет парсить данные для поля hstore.

Можно ли при выполнении запросов к определенным полям на стороне Postgres-а автоматически производить преобразование hstore<->record, например. Ну, или хотя бы hstor<->json?

Скорее  всего, можно написать какой-то триггер, но хорошо бы пример посмотреть. Может кто подскажет?

Comment: а почему не хранить эти данные в json/jsonb?

Comment: Там будет информация типа email / номера телефонов и т.п. поля, по которым нужен будет поиск. Я думал по hstore создать индекс. А делать типа `like %чего-то-там%` при использовании json думаю будет слишком медленно.

Comment: в чем проблема? - jsonb позволяет иметь прекрасные gin индексы! обычный json, впрочем, тоже индексируется на ура a la "create index table_idx on table (json->>'email')"

Comment: А вот по поводу индексов для json - ссылочку не кинете?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html

Answer (score 1):

Альтернатива, если `::json` не подходит:

```
select to_json(('"a"=>1, "b"=>2'::hstore));
```

Comment: Да дело не в этом.. При использовании конструктора все строка обрабатывается как название поля и вылезает ошибка `Statement could not be executed (42703 - 7 - ERROR:  column alm_leads.to_json\"(\"data\") does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

```
select ('"a"=>1, "b"=>2'::hstore)::json;
         json         
----------------------
{"a": "1", "b": "2"}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Если использовать конструктор запросов в Zend Framework 2 - проблематично указать `::json` в select. Поэтому и нужен какой-нить триггер на запись/чтение полей hstore.

Comment: я не копенгаген в зенд, но по моему опыту "проблематично" обычно не равно "не возможно". а если хочется городить проблемы и городушки, обильно засаливая их триггерами, то какая проблема - создать рядом с hstore полем json контейнер, сделать триггер на инсерт-апдейт и кастить в json содержимое hstore. но зачем?...

Comment: Я ж и прошу - дайте пример :) На существующем коде проще разобраться как сделать.

Comment: пример чего? триггера на insert/update? примеров полно в документации и в сети

Comment: Ссылка была б очень к стати. Но, могу и сам погуглить, вы правы...